# Android LinearLayout fill until bottom of screen

Tags: android, android-activity, android-linearlayout

I have an Android activity that is composed by:
FrameLayout > ScrollView > LinearLayout > ListView

My ListView is my last component and I would like that its height size would go from the ending of the previous component up to the bottom of the screen. **Problem**: unfortunately right now its size is only the height size is only the size of 1 row.

I have set all layout_height to match_parent property, but no effect.

**Question**: would you know how to make my ListView occupy all the height space down to the bottom of the available screen?

Thank you!

**XML**:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="it.bitrack.fabio.bitrack.ScheduleView"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Select an asset"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/assetSpinner"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/assetBookingLinearLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView9"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="Booking schedule"
                    android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView12"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text="From: "
                        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/fromDatetimeTextView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="Date and time" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/setFromDatetimeImageButton"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_my_calendar" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView13"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text="To: "
                        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/toDatetimeTextView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="Date and time" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/setToDatetimeImageButton"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_my_calendar" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/assetBookingButton"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Proceed with booking" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/assetBookingsLinearLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView8"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="Current bookings"
                    android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/assetBookingsListView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>>
    </ScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this layout code:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Select an asset"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/assetSpinner"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/assetBookingLinearLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView9"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="Booking schedule"
                    android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView12"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text="From: "
                        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/fromDatetimeTextView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="Date and time" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/setFromDatetimeImageButton"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_my_calendar" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView13"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text="To: "
                        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/toDatetimeTextView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="Date and time" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/setToDatetimeImageButton"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_my_calendar" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/assetBookingButton"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Proceed with booking" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/assetBookingsLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/scrollview"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Current bookings"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/assetBookingsListView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Couple of suggestion:

1. Dont's use `listview` inside `ScrollView`...
2. use `RelativeLayout` as a root element to align views one after
   another.
3. For `scrollView` use `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` and
   `android:fillViewport="true"`

Output:

[image]